# Difference between pygame.draw and pygame.gfxdraw

Tags: python, pygame

My question is simple:  What is the difference between using `pygame.draw` and `pygame.gfxdraw`?  I've looked on the pygame documentation, but no one has told what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `draw` function is a bit more stable, and also a bit faster that `gfxdraw`, although `gfxdraw` has more options, not only along the lines of antialiasing, but also drawing shapes. `pygame.draw` has only nine functions, whereas `pygame.gfxdraw` has 22 options, which include all 9 of the options supplied by `draw`. I recommend using `gfxdraw` even though its is "experimental" because it has more capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

`gfxdraw` allows anti-aliasing for all shapes, where `draw`only adds antialiasing to lines. I use `gfxdraw` by default. It has been marked 'experimental' for a long time now, but I've not had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I Don't use pygame!**

According to the [gfxdraw doc page](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html), it "*Wraps SDL_gfx primatives*", and so offers it as an API for those already familiar with it. It also appears to offers a little bit more than the more primitive normal `draw`. There also appears to be a few semantic differences here and there, so you'll need to compare each to its closest counterpart, and not assume anything.

As a final note, gfxdraw is *experimental*, and you should always take that into consideration before using it.

I hope this helps! :)